# Why docker pings second-level domain

Tags: docker

I try to push my docker image into local registry.

```
docker tag COMPANY_NAME/IMAGE_NAME:TAG_NAME docker-registiry.company.ru:5000/COMPANY_NAME/IMAGE_NAME:latest
docker push COMPANY_NAME/IMAGE_NAME:TAG_NAME
```

But I have an error

```
Get https://company.ru/v1/_ping: x509: certificate is valid for
```

Why docker push get ping to second level domain not to docker-registiry.company.ru:5000?

Comment: The correct push syntax would be:
`docker push docker-registiry.company.ru:5000/COMPANY_NAME/IMAGE_NAME:TAG_NAME`. Not sure however if this is related to the error you see.

Comment: @AlexanderBlock Thanks it works